# How to change Server API as CGI/FastCGI in the Apache2 server in ubuntu18.04

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, fastcgi

I need to configure Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit machine for apache server to work CGI/FastCGI.
I am able to run PHP as apachehandler and FPM/Fastcgi but it is not running as CGI/FastCGI.
How can I configure Ubunutu 18.04 apache server to run API server as CGI/FastCGI.
What is the procedure to run Apache as CGI/FastCGI.